# how to write a batch file to execute TCL files

Tags: batch-file, tcl, ns2

I am a beginner of Linux (Ubuntu 12.10). I want to create a batch file to control my TCL file, and I want my TCL to run for several times.

For example, I want the batch file to do the following things:

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++){
    sudo ns test.tcl $i
}
```

I want my tcl file to accept parameters ($i) so that I can use the parameter in the tcl file.

Can anyone tell me what can I do? or give me a direction?

Thanks in advance.

ps. I wrote the loop inside my TCL file but failed. My code was like:

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++){

    set ns [new Simulator]
    .... 
    ....(my NS code)
    ....
    $ns run

}
```

It ran only for $i==1, so I am thinking of writing the loop outside the tcl script.

PS2. Hi guys, I am sorry for not expressing myself clear. I did follow the TCL syntax. My real code is the following:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
    set ns [new Simulator]
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $ns run
}
```

And I solved this problem by rearranging my code to the following:

```
set ns [new Simulator]
for {set i 1} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
$ns run
```

Now it runs 99 times. I don't know why, though :P

Thank you guys anyway :)

Comment: Q: Why do you need a separate (bash?) script?  Why not just do the whole thing in TCL (which is itself a perfectly good scripting language)?

Comment: I tried to write the loop inside the tcl file but that only run for once (when $i == 1), and it didn't run $i==2~99.

Comment: The 99-times problem is a classic “fencepost error”; if you're doing 100 iterations from 0, use `for {set i 0} {$i < 100} {incr i} …`, and if you're starting from 1, use `for {set i 1} {$i <= 100} {incr i} …`. **Notice the different comparison operator!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, are you sure you're writing Tcl? This isn't the syntax for Tcl. What you might be looking for is:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
    set ns [new Simulator]
    .... 
    ....(my NS code)
    ....
    $ns run
}
```

You use braces everywhere. The only time I can think of using brackets is for arrays, but I don't think I know Tcl deep enough to ascertain this, and your start conditions, test and next commands are in their own braces and `incr i` is equivalent to `i++`.

Now, `new` is not a built-in function in Tcl. Do you have a proc named `new` somewhere? If you don't, then you'll get errors.

Answer (score 0):

A [Tcl script](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) is very simple, it consists of a number of commands and each command consists of a command name followed by a number of arguments. Even control structures are commands. The [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/for.htm) command takes 4 arguments: a start script, a test expression, a next script and a body script. Like all other command arguments (and command names), you can quote `for`'s arguments any way you want, or even use variables and other substitutions for some of them, but usually you don't want that before they're sent to the command, so you use braces:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is the expression

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++){
```

This loop only runs 99 times, which might not be what you want, besides the wrong syntax. Others suggest the correct `for` loop, so please go with that.  If you still think Tcl `for` loop is too complicated, may I suggest an alternative:

```
package require Tclx

loop i 0 100 {
    # i will run from 0 to 99
}
```

The only disadvantage of this approach is you have to pull in the `Tclx` package, but if your script already uses `Tclx`, why not?